# How to accept a color input from user and display it using js

Tags: javascript, html, colors

/*
Accept color input from user and then apply it to the variable named "message".
*/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textcol, message = "Nice color choice";
    textcol=window.prompt("Enter a color:");
    document.getElementById(message).style.color = textcol;
    document.writeln(message);
</script>
```

Comment: `message` inside `getElementById` needs quotes. : `document.getElementById("message")...` Your variable 'message' is not the same as the ID you're looking for. Different names would clarify it. ` var msg`, for ex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var textcol,
 message = 'Nice color choice';
 textcol = window.prompt('Enter a color:');

document.writeln(`<span style="color:${textcol}">${message}</span>`);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist Saeed.